# Нужна помощь в понимании ООП PHP

Tags: php, ооп, конструктор

```
<?php
class arrayWorker
{
    protected $array = [];
    public function __construct ($a, $b) {
        $this->a=$a;
        $this->b=$b;
    }
    protected function fill() {
        $array = range($this->a, $this->b);
        return $array;
    }
    private function reindex($array) {
        $a = $array;
        $min = 0;
        $max = 0;
        $count = count ($a);
        for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if ($a[$i] > $a[$max]) $max = $i;
            if ($a[$i] < $a[$min]) $min = $i;
        }
        $a[$min] += $a[$max];
        $a[$max] = $a[$min] - $a[$max];
        $a[$min] = $a[$min] - $a[$max];
        print_r($a);
        return $array;
    }
    public function dump($a) {
        $min = 0;
        $max = 0;
        $count = count ($a);
        for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
            if ($a[$i] > $a[$max]) $max = $i;
            if ($a[$i] < $a[$min]) $min = $i;
        }
        return $max + $min;
    }
}
$value = new arrayWorker(1,100);
```

Здравствуйте. **У меня есть вот такое задание:**

В файле ArrayWorker.php описать класс ArrayWorker имеющий защищенное свойство $array — пустой массив, и состоящий из следующих методов:

•   fill() — заполняет свойство $array случайными числами от 1 до 100 (длина массива произвольная). Метод защищенный.

•   reindex() — меняет местами максимальное и минимальное значение свойства $array. Метод защищенный.

•   dump() — выводит сумму индексов максимального и минимального значений свойства $array. Метод общедоступный.

В конструкторе класса выполняются методы fill() и reindex().

На странице объявить объект класса ArrayWorker и вызвать метод dump().

**Я написал все методы и теперь мне нужно понять что нужно делать с конструктором? Подскажите пожалуйста**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В соответствии с заданием:

```
public function __construct ($size) {
    $this->size = $size;
    $this->fill();
    $this->reindex();
}
```

метод `fill()` должен заполнять случайными числами $array, а вы используете range дающий поледовательные числа

```
protected function fill() {
    $this->array = ..... ;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, подправил